# Repeat CSS Animation Infinitely

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm getting a bit stuck on how to get this animation to repeat infinitely. It's essentially, rotating through a few text spans using CSS animations. I've tried a few ways, but it ends up stacking the text due to the animation repeating the first animation and fading in.

```css
.rotatingText {
  font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

.rotatingText-adjective {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  top: 0;
}

.rotatingText-adjective:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: .5s;
}

.rotatingText-adjective:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 1.75s;
}

.rotatingText-adjective:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 50px, 0);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, -25px, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="text-white heading-xl mb-2 position-relative">
  <p class="rotatingText">
    I'll make your website&hellip;

    <span class="rotatingText-adjective">beautiful</span>
    <span class="rotatingText-adjective">maintainable</span>
    <span class="rotatingText-adjective">perfect </span>
  </p>
</h1>
```

Comment: You need `animation-iteration-count: infinite;`, but then you'll also have to adapt your animations to make the texts disappear again before the next one comes in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `animation-iteration-count: infinite;` and appropriate calculate animation steps. Let's assume that the whole animation will take 6s, so you need to split this into 3 animations, 2s each. To allow animation finish in 1/3 of the whole time (2s), you need to finish it at 33% (it should stay invisible during the next 4s). Each next animation should have delay with the duration of previous animations.

Here is an example (I changed duration to 6s for better calculation):

```
.rotatingText {
  font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

.rotatingText-adjective {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  top: 0;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 6s;
}

.rotatingText-adjective:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-name: rotate;
}

.rotatingText-adjective:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.rotatingText-adjective:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 50px, 0);
  }
  16% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, -25px, 0);
  }
}
```